# proving that $f(x)=\frac{1}{\ln(x)}-x+2,\forall x\in\ (0,1)$ has no solution

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

I have the function: $$f(x)=\frac{1}{\ln(x)}-x+2,\forall x\in\ (0,1)$$
I have alreaday found the monotonicity of this function (strictly decreasing at $(0,1)$) and the $$\lim_{x\to 0+}{f(x)}=2$$ $$\lim_{x\to 1-}{f(x)}=-\infty$$
So the range of $f$ is: $f((0,1))\rightarrow(-\infty,2)$,
because $f$ is continuous.

Now I want to prove that the equation $(x+1)\cdot \ln(x)=1$ has no solution at $(0,1)$. Any hints?

Comment: Your end question can even be solved if you didn't provide all the other info preceding it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hint:$$(x+1)\ln{x}<0$$ for all $0<x<1$.